# Как убрать язык с которого переходишь? request()->path();

Tags: php, laravel

Как получить get curent url только конец ? http://site.ru/ru**/newpage**

```
   /en/<?php echo request()->path(); ?>
```

показывает http://site.ru/ru/http://site.ru/ru/en/news
Как убрать язык с которого переходишь?

Comment: Думаю роуты тут не при чем. Надо смотреть код смены языка. Там где то идет редирект на главную. Надо заменить на редирект на текущую страницу, но с другим языком.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант (явно не панацея и скорее всего делается как-то более красиво), но имеет право на существование

```
/ru/<?php echo str_replace('http://site.ru/ru/', '', URL::current()); ?>
```

таким образом Вы отсечете из строки лишнее и получите желаемое.

Comment: не помогло(  к сожалению но большое вам спасибо

Answer (score -1):

Тупо решил вопрос не кидайтесь камнями)

```
http://site.ru/ru/<?php echo mb_substr(request()->path(), 3, 100) ?>
http://site.ru/en/<?php echo mb_substr(request()->path(), 3, 100) ?>
http://site.ru/kz/<?php echo mb_substr(request()->path(), 3, 100) ?>
```

mb_substr сделано что бы съедать /ru, /en, /kz

```
request()->path();
```

выдает все после имени сайта

Comment: злые люди! рейтинг минусанули( за тупой ответ?